# Shuffle records and sequential records in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, shuffle

I have written a SQL query which returns me a shuffled data by using NEWID()
in SQL Server 2012.

Scenario:
I have a table in which we have questions in table - "tblquest" whereas in "tblquestLinked" table we have a linked question which is related to main question in "tblquest" table,
Now the below query outputs the shuffled data correctly.

```
select ROW_NUMBER() Over (Order by newid()) as sNo,*
from (select q.ID AS [QID], q.Question,
q.Solution,
isnull(q.IsLinked,0) as IsLinked, ql.LinkQuestion
from tblquest q
left join tblQuestLinked ql
on q.ID = ql.QID) a
```

[image]

I want the dataset returned by query should also have a linked question in it, But should not be shuffled, Instead should be very next row to linked "main" question.

**EDIT**

As these set of questions will be presented to an Online Examination application, the shuffling of the questions is must.

One Main question can have 0 to many Linked questions.
And the linked question appears very next row to that corresponding 'Main" Question.
As this will be passed to UI and it will provide the questions based on sNO ( Serial No)

Please find the screenshot (desired result):

[image]

*Schema Scripts :*

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblQuest](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[IsLinked] [bit] NULL,
[Question] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
[Solution] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_tblQuest] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,        ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblQuestLinked](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[QID] [int] NULL,
[LinkQuestion] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[CreatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblQuestLinked] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
)
GO


INSERT [dbo].[tblQuest] ([IsLinked], [Question], [Solution]) VALUES (0, N'Which of ... 1 ', 'Solution 1 ... ')
INSERT [dbo].[tblQuest] ([IsLinked], [Question], [Solution]) VALUES (0, N'Which of ... 2 ', 'Solution 2 ... ')
INSERT [dbo].[tblQuest] ([IsLinked], [Question], [Solution]) VALUES (0, N'Which of ... 3 ', 'Solution 3 ... ')
INSERT [dbo].[tblQuest] ([IsLinked], [Question], [Solution]) VALUES (0, N'Which of ... 4 ', 'Solution 4 ... ')
INSERT [dbo].[tblQuest] ([IsLinked], [Question], [Solution]) VALUES (0, N'Which of ... 5 ', 'Solution 5 ... ')
INSERT [dbo].[tblQuest] ([IsLinked], [Question], [Solution]) VALUES (0, N'Which of ... 6 ', 'Solution 6 ... ')
INSERT [dbo].[tblQuest] ([IsLinked], [Question], [Solution]) VALUES (1, N'Which of ... 7 ', 'Solution 7 ... ')


INSERT [dbo].[tblQuestLinked] ( [QID], [LinkQuestion]) VALUES (7, N'LINKED Q : SUB LINKED')
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @GordonLinoff - updated the question

Comment: Please provide the same data in usable format, preferably in create table + insert clauses or at least as text

Comment: Your model is very bizarre. Shouldn't the table **tblQuestLinked** link two rows of **tblQuest** rather than being a new entity. What would be the value of the columns "Solution" and "IsLinked" in your select for question coming from tblQuestLinked? Also you might have legitimate duplicate in the column "QID".

Comment: Columns "Solution" and "IsLinked" are of **tblQuest**.
Yes agreed for "QID" Just for understanding I have put in select statement. Front end needs the sNo column which is Serial No.

Comment: Yes but since your select will be comprised of rows coming from both **tblQuest** and **tblQuestLinked** what will you use for the fields "Solution" and "IsLinked" for the rows coming from tblQuestLinked since that table do not possess such columns.

Comment: Can the linked questions belong to several "main" questions? Otherwise you could just have the link to main id in the linked question without having the extra table

Comment: No the Linked questions are not common to "main" questions. Each Main question can have 0 to many linked questions.

Comment: If you've deliberately obscured the data with those white stripes, I want to let you know that it's still perfectly readable ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood this correctly, you want the linked questions always under the main question. This is one way to do that:

```
select
  q.id, case when Type = 0 then Question else LinkQuestion end, Solution
from
(
  select row_number() over (order by newid()) as ORD, *
  from tblQuest q
) q
outer apply (
  select 0 as Type, 0 as QID, convert(varchar(max), NULL) as LinkQuestion
  union all
  select 1, QID, l.LinkQuestion
  from tblQuestLinked l where q.ID = l.QID
) x
order by q.ORD, x.Type, x.QID
```

Example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6513d1/1)

Comment: I tried this Fiddle and works perfectly as needed. As these questions will be put on User screen for "Exam" so Shuffling is a must, and it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that there cannot be any linked question without a root question, you can simply select all records from both tables and glue them with `UNION ALL`. Then we want the sort order based on the ID they have in common first. But just ordering by qid, newid() would actually sort by the ID, not randomly. So we need a random function that takes the ID and gives us a deterministic "random" value based on it: `RAND(qid)`. But still, this would give us the same order on every execution, so we add a randomizer:

```
ORDER BY rand(rand(convert(int, getdate())) - qid)
```

It shows that SQL Server's `RAND` is a bit flawed when it comes to seeding (see my comment on that). This worked for me:

```
ORDER BY rand((datepart(mm, getdate()) * 100000) +
              (datepart(ss, getdate()) * 1000) +
               datepart(ms, getdate()) ^ qid)
```

As two different seeds can still lead to the same random number, we'll need to add `, qid` to this, so as to make sure the two linked entries get together. Moreover we add `, islinked desc` in order to get the question before the linked question.

The whole query:

```
select qid, question, solution, islinked
from
(
  select 
    id as qid, 
    question,
    solution,
    isnull(islinked, 0) as islinked, 
    id as linkkey
  from tblquest
  union all
  select 
    id as qid, 
    linkquestion as question,
    null as solution,
    0 as islinked, 
    qid as linkkey
  from tblquestlinked
) both
order by rand((datepart(mm, getdate()) * 100000) +
              (datepart(ss, getdate()) * 1000) +
               datepart(ms, getdate()) ^ qid), qid, islinked desc;
```

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/476fd/2

Comment: I tried this in SQL Fiddle, but the rows are always in same order, and just by luck, the linked question is below the question 7: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/476fd/1

Comment: That the linked question comes after its question has nothing to do with luck here. However, you are right that the records always come in the same order. SQL Server's RAND is a bit flawed it seems. Although it takes an integer as a seed, it seems it doesn't use it properly; once the numbers are very high you always get the same "random" number. Not knowing how that seed integer is actually used, It is quite hard to find a way to make it create a random order really. I'll update my answer accordingly, but JamesZ's answer is preferrable by far. A great idea to use SQL Server's OUTER APPLY here.